# PHP search MySQL table with dropdown box

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am trying to create a search box that searches the county field of the database. If the criteria matches then the records will be displayed in the table. I have got the different counties in the dropdown box however when I click the record the table does not change. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php
require_once("includes/session.php");
include_once("includes/masterinclude.php");

$preferences = getPreferences();
$category = "";
$attribute1 = ""; $attribute2 = ""; $attriute3 = ""; $attribute4 = "";
$top_level="0";

$name = $_GET['members'];
$information = getInformationPage($name);
$infopagename=$information->IN_NAME;
//meta data for information pages now taken from the information table
$pageTitle = $information->IN_NAME . html_entity_decode($information->IN_TITLE);
$pageMetaDescription = html_entity_decode($information->IN_META_DESC);
$pageMetaKeywords = html_entity_decode($information->IN_META_KEYWORDS);
$pageCustomHead = html_entity_decode($information->IN_CUSTOM_HEAD, ENT_QUOTES);

//initialise screen fields
$selected_member = "";
$id = "";
$username = ""; $username_original = "";
$password = ""; $password_original = "";
$password_test = "";
$title = "MR"; $first_name = ""; $last_name = ""; $company_name = "";
$address1 = ""; $address2 = ""; $town = ""; $county = ""; $country = ""; $postcode = ""; $phone = ""; $mobile = ""; $email = "";
$member_confirmed = "N";
$ast_first = 0; $ast_last = 0; $ast_company = 0; $ast_add1 = 0; $ast_add2 = 0; $ast_town = 0; $ast_county = 0; $ast_country = 0; $ast_post = 0; $ast_phone = 0;
$ast_mobile = 0; $ast_email = 0;
$ast_user = 0; $ast_pass = 0; $ast_passconf = 0;

$members = Get_All_Members("ALL");
$_GET['searchdata'] = $_POST['SEARCH_DATA']; $_GET['searchmember'] = $_POST['MEMBER'];

include_once("includes/header.php");
?>

<!-- start: Page header / Breadcrumbs -->

<div id="breadcrumbs">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="breadcrumbs"> 
        <a href="/">Home</a><i class="icon-angle-right"></i>Stockists
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- end: Page header / Breadcrumbs -->


<!-- start: Container -->
<div id="container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">

        <form class="form-horizontal form-box" role="form" name="enter_thumb" action="/stockists.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_discount_table();"> 

        <!-- start: Page section -->
        <section class="span12">
            <div class="row-fluid shop-result">
                <div class="inner darken clearfix">
                <h1>Stockists</h1>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="row-fluid">

            <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-4">Search County: </label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <Input class="form-control" name="SEARCH_DATA" type="text" size="72" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['SEARCH_DATA']) ? $_POST['SEARCH_DATA'] : "" ?>"/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <Input name="SEARCH" type="submit" value="search" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <select name="search_results" id="jumpMenu" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,1)">
                        <option value="#">Choose from...</option>
                            <?php
                            if (isset($_POST['SEARCH_DATA'])){
                            $members = Search_member($_POST['SEARCH_DATA']);
                            foreach($members as $m){
                            if(isset($_POST['SELECTED_MEMBER']) and $_POST['SELECTED_MEMBER'] == $m->MB_COUNTY){
                            $selected = "selected";
                            }else{
                            $selected = "";
                            }
                            echo "<option value=\"/stockists.php?searchdata=" . $_POST['SEARCH_DATA'] . "&searchmember=" . $m->MB_COUNTY . "\"" . $selected . ">" . $m->MB_COUNTY . " - " . html_entity_decode($m->MB_COUNTY) . "</option>";
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                    </select>

                    <input type="hidden" name="SELECTED_MEMBER" value="<?php echo (isset($selected_member) ? $selected_member : "") ?>"/>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">

            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                   Name
                </th>
                <th>
                  Website
                </th>
                <th>
                   Phone
                </th>
                <th>
                    Address
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>


            <?php if($county != ""): ?> 
            <?php
                foreach($members as $m){
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>";
                            echo "<span class=\"member_line\">" . $m->MB_COMPANY . "</span>";
                        echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>";
                            echo "<a href=\"http://" . $m->MB_MOBILE . "\">" . $m->MB_MOBILE . "</a>";
                        echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>";
                            echo "<span class=\"member_line\">" . $m->MB_PHONE . "</span>";
                        echo "</td>";
        //              echo "<td>";
        //                  echo "<a href=\"mailto:" . $m->MB_EMAIL . "\"><span style=\"color:#669999;\" class=\"member_line\">" . $m->MB_EMAIL . "</span></a>";
        //              echo "</td>";-->
                        echo "<td>";
                            echo "<span class=\"member_line\">" . $m->MB_ADDRESS1 . ", " . $m->MB_ADDRESS2 . ", " . $m->MB_TOWN . ", " . $m->MB_COUNTY . ", " . $m->MB_POSTCODE . "</span>";
                        echo "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>"; 
             ?>
             </table>

             <?php endif; ?>

             </div>
            </div>
            </form>  
        </section>
        <!-- end: Page section -->


        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- end: Container -->



<?php
  include_once("includes/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: Are any errors shown? What SQL are you using? What is the database schema you're accessing? Do you get some output but the wrong output? Posting a block of code without any explanation of what should happen (and no description of what information should be coming back from your functions) is not helpful. Log output from all your functions into a file so you can narrow down where the problem lies

Comment: No errors are being shown. There is no output at all the table is there however it remains blank. They're are records in the database and the database is being connected. Sorry I am new to posting questions online will try harder in the future.

Comment: If the DB is being connected to, what is the output of your query? Dump each row to a log file as you retrieve them (CSV/print_r/var_export) so you can check that the data is actually sensible. If you're using JavaScript, check for errors and log the output there to the console

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP page isn't going to be able to change what is in the bale without a page refresh or alternatively using javascript to rewrite the page.

I see you're using a MM_jumpMenu() JS function when the drop down change. This function will need to retrieve the data for your selection then rewrite the table to include the new data. If you are already doing this in the JS code then we'll need to see that code to find what the problem is.

An alternative to this would be to do away with the JS and allow the form to submit the page to itself. Then  at the top of the page read the selected value that has been passed from the form, load the data and write the bale accordingly.

Comment: Yes I have been trying to refresh, when I start the form I have action="/stockists.php". When I click the search button the page reloads and the counties appear in the drop down box. The table shows nothing it remains empty. There are records in the database. For some reason the IF statement is not working and the records are not being displayed!

Comment: The if statement is checking if the $county is empty. I can see where you default it to be empty but I can't see you ever putting anything in it so it is always empty. If the valuse of country is coming back from the form submission you need to check something like $_POST['country']